# Linearity of expectation not respected

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I have found that `Expectation` gives different results if I use the fact that expectation is linear and evaluate it on every term independently.

I reduced my problem to the following code snippet. I use Mathematica 10.0.2:

```
f = x1 + x1 x2 z;
d = BernoulliDistribution[1/2 - z];
t = TransformedDistribution[
   f, {x1 \[Distributed] d, x2 \[Distributed] d}];
e[x_] := 
  Expand @ Simplify[Expectation[x, {x1 \[Distributed] d, x2 \[Distributed] t}]]
e[f]
Total[e /@ List @@ f]
```

Since expectation is linear, the last two expressions should evaluate to the same expression, but they don't. I get instead:

```
 1/2 - (3 z)/4 - (7 z^2)/8 + z^3/4 + (3 z^4)/2 - z^5

 3/4 - (15 z)/8 + z^2/4 + (3 z^3)/2 - z^4
```

Is my understanding correct and this is a bug, or Mathematica is correct and I got it wrong?

Comment: @Coolwater : are you sure? this lecture asserts that linearity of expectation holds even for dependent terms http://www.cse.iitd.ac.in/~mohanty/col106/Resources/linearity_expectation.pdf

Comment: `FullForm@f` gives `Plus[x1,Times[x1,x2,z]]` and `List @@ f` gives `{x1, x1 x2 z}`. But the expectation of a product of independent random variables is the product of their expectations, not their sum.
`Expectation` expects all listed distributions to be independent of each other.

Comment: I don't know if this adds anything to the discussion but the two results become identical if `z` is set to some specific value between 0 and 1/2 (prior to defining `f`).

Answer (score 3):

EXTENDED COMMENT.  I cannot reproduce your problem. Which OS and Mathematica version are you using? Have you tried starting with a fresh kernel?

```
$Version

(*  "10.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 9, 2015)"  *)

f = x1 + x1 x2 z;

d = BernoulliDistribution[1/2 - z];

t = TransformedDistribution[f, {x1 \[Distributed] d, x2 \[Distributed] d}];

e[x_] := Expand@
  Simplify[Expectation[x, {x1 \[Distributed] d, x2 \[Distributed] t}]]

e[f]

(*  1/2 - (3*z)/4 - (7*z^2)/8 + z^3/4 + 
   (3*z^4)/2 - z^5  *)

Total[e /@ List @@ f]

(*  1/2 - (3*z)/4 - (7*z^2)/8 + z^3/4 + 
   (3*z^4)/2 - z^5  *)

% == %%

(*  True  *)
```

Comment: With Mathematica 10.0.2 on Win8 64 bit I get the same output as the OP.

Comment: @MarcoBreitig - on my Mac it also works correctly with versions 9.0.1 and 10.3.0. Apparently the problem was introduced in version 10 and corrected in version 10.3.0

Comment: What does `List @@ f` produce? See my other comment on the question.

Comment: @MarcoBreitig - from the documentation for [TransformedDistribution](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedDistribution.html) the form of the definition of `t` implies that the variables are independent.  Were they dependent, the `TransformedDistribution` argument would use a bivariate or multivariate distribution for the variables.

Comment: @bon-hanlon: Yes, but I was arguing that E[X Y]=E[X] E[Y] for X, Y independent r.v., but `Apply[List, X Y]` gives `{X,Y}`. The expectations might be correctly calculated, but ´Total[e[X], e[Y]]´ is wrong if the initial expression was ´X Y´.

Comment: @Marco - He is applying List to a sum (not a product) so that `List @@ f` evaluates to `{x1, x1 x2 z}` and due to the precedence of operators `e /@ List @@ f` returns `{e[x1], e[x1 x2 z]}`

Comment: My version is ""10.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (December 4, 2014)"" and the problem persists with a fresh kernel and your code snippet.

Answer (score 3):

I have just had a quick squiz ... and express my concerns.

First, I think such questions would be clearer if you first stated it in statistical/mathematical terms (not Mma code) ... and then provided your mma code. Then we can see if you are doing what you want to be doing. I am not quite sure what you want to be doing.

Second, since `t` is defined in terms of `TransformedDistribution` which is a black box, how do you even know what you are doing, or linking to? To make this explicit, derive the pmf of the `TransformedDistribution`:

```
d = BernoulliDistribution[1/2 - z];
t = PDF[TransformedDistribution[x1 + x1 x2 z, {x1 \[Distributed] d, x2 \[Distributed] d}], z]
```

returns:

```
Piecewise[{{1/2, z == 0}, {-(3/4), z == 1}}, 0]
```

so `t` is just a function of parameter `z`, yet you are defining an expectation where

```
 x2 \[Distributed] t
```

That looks like trouble to me.

Comment: For whatever it's worth, I wholeheartedly agree about providing some statistical background rather than just the *Mathematica* code.  I assume you used `z` at the end of the PDF statement rather than some other symbol to show what trouble can arise.  If one puts in say `y` instead of `z`, then the correct density is provided (assuming the constant `z` is between zero and 1/2).  This makes `t` a density function rather than a distribution function.

Answer (score 2):

I think the sequence of code is not constructed properly.  First, we need to start with the correct expectation of `f` which we can do directly assuming that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are independent random variables distributed as $Bernoulli(1/2-z)$:

$$E(f)=E(x_1+x_1 x_2 z)=E(x_1)+E(x_1)E(x_2)z=(1/2-z)+(1/2-z)(1/2-z)z=1/2-3z/4-z^2+z^3$$

Neither one of the two expressions in the question result in that value so something must be wrong with either my construction or the OP's.

If we do the following

```
f = x1 + x1 x2 z;
d = BernoulliDistribution[1/2 - z];
t = TransformedDistribution[f, {x1 \[Distributed] d, x2 \[Distributed] d}];
```

then `t` is the distribution of the random variable `f` and the expectation is

```
Expand[Expectation[f, f \[Distributed] t]]
(* 1/2 - (3 z)/4 - z^2 + z^3 *)
```

We could also call the random variable as `y` and get the same answer:

```
Expand[Expectation[y, y \[Distributed] t]]
```

But the function defined above in the question

```
e[x_] := Expand @ Simplify[Expectation[x, {x1 \[Distributed] d, x2 \[Distributed] t}]]
```

should not be expected to provide the correct expectation as for one thing `x2` is not distributed with distribution `t`.  But let's say that `x1` has distribution `d` and `x2` has distribution `t` with `x1` and `x2` independent (which by listing the two distributions in the format as you do, *Mathematica* expects those to be independent).

The expectation of `x1 + x1 x2 z` will be

```
Expand[(1/2 - z) + (1/2 - z) (1/2 - (3 z)/4 - z^2 + z^3) z]
(* 1/2 - (3 z)/4 - (7 z^2)/8 + z^3/4 + (3 z^4)/2 - z^5 *)
```

which is one of the outputs you found and that is not the desired expectation.